# OnGet not being called after OnPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

new to asp.net core, created a asp.net core web app (not mvc) and made the following demo code to test posting a form.  When i post the form it does not seem to be running the onGet method when it refreshes the page after the post.  What am i am missing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post"><input type="submit" /></form>
        <h1>Get Message = @ViewData["ON_GET_MESSAGE"]</h1>
        <h1>Post Message = @ViewData["ON_POST_MESSAGE"]</h1>

        @RenderBody()

    </body>
</html>
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Fiscal_AP_Log.Pages
{

    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

        public void OnGet()
        {
            this.ViewData["ON_GET_MESSAGE"] = "OnGet()";
        }

        public void OnPost()
        {
            this.ViewData["ON_POST_MESSAGE"] = "OnPost()";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: _" When i post the form it does not seem to be running the onGet method when it refreshes the page after the post"_ - why do you think it should?

Comment: @GuruStron it is my understanding that onpost refreshes the page when it is done?  is this not the case?  if so when i hit submit how do i get it to execute the onpost code and then refresh the page.  eventually it will have a table of data that should show the new record after the post?

Comment: To invoke the `OnGet` you can for example redirect to it in the `OnPost`. Try adding something like `return RedirectToPage("./Index");` at the end of `OnPost`.

Comment: When you submit the from , it should invoke `OnPost()` method, So you want to call `OnGet()` again after submitting the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handlers (like `OnGet` and `OnPost`) should describe exactly what should happen, for example if you want to redirect to the index page (GET) then you can use `RedirectToPage` (sometimes you don't want to redirect, for example if posted model is not a valid one and user should fix validation errors):

```cs
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    this.ViewData["ON_POST_MESSAGE"] = "OnPost()";
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) for more info and examples.